# find the executable jar file location in java

Tags: java

Is is possible to find my executable jar file running location, from that jar file jave code,

For example I may run one particular jar file from d:\test\finloc.jar, It should print the path as

```
  d:\\test
```

I may run from C:\users\GJ\Documents\findloc.jar, then its output should be like

```
  C:\\users\GJ\\Documents\\
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code outputs the path from where the application starts.
In your case, the jar file.

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```